# Cannot add custom view controller to UIScrollVIew

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiscrollview, paging

I'm trying to make an application that uses a UIScrollView to page between an indeterminate number of dynamically generated custom view controllers. Unfortunately, when I try the code shown below, all I get is a blank screen. Additionally, the nslog statement that I put right after the subview is supposedly added to the UIScrollView always says that the UIScrollView has zero subviews. I'm totally baffled by this problem and would greatly appreciate any help.

```
- (void)loadView 
{
   [super loadView];

   scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

   viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
   CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

   CGFloat width = screenBounds.size.width * screenScale;
   CGFloat height = screenBounds.size.height * screenScale;

   scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width * [routes count], height);

    for( int i = 0; i < [arrayWithDataForViewControllers count]; i++)
    {
       ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];

       controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(width*i, 20, width, height);

        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
         NSLog(@"SUBVIEWS %d", [[scrollView subviews] count]);
         [viewControllers addObject:controller];
    }   
}
```

Comment: I have a hunch that your scrollView isn't even initialized in the loadView function. That's why you see 0 in the subViews.

Comment: You were right; and I moved the code to viewDidLoad, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: What is initializing your UIScrollView? If you are using a nib make sure you are connecting the IBOutlet to it. If no you should move all your code back into loadView and explicitly alloc/initWithFrame your UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ViewController's view outside of the scrollview - chances are that it's view property is nil.

Comment: I checked the view of the ViewControllers and they aren't nil. :(